# Get And Set return Null

Tags: java, field, getter-setter

My Get and Set return null.
I think it's missing something on my Set method.

My Authen.java :

```
public class Authen {   
    String sessionID;

    public void setSessionID(String sessionID) {
        this.sessionID = sessionID;
    }

    public String getSessionID(){
        return this.sessionID;
    }
}
```

My Set method :

```
        String id="1234";
        Authen at = new Authen();
        at.setSessionID(id);
```

My Get method returns null when I log sID

```
Authen at = new Authen();
String sID = at.getSessionID();
```

Comment: Your last snippet always return `null`, because you make yourself a new `Authen` object, and then try to retrieve the session id when it's never set.

Comment: A setter doesn't return anything

Comment: And where is class constructor?

Comment: if setSessionID on A.class to authen.java I want to getSessionID on B.class from authen.java How can i do this method ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as it's very trivial and basic. If ya read the first chapter of any Java book, you would be able to answer your *question*.

Answer (score 0):

You're redeclaring `at` which is going to remove any values you set.

After you set the id, don't create a new `Authen` object

So change this:

```
String id="1234";
Authen at = new Authen();
at.setSessionID(id);

Authen at = new Authen(); // This is where you create a new EMPTY authen
String sID = at.getSessionID();
```

to:

```
String id="1234";
Authen at = new Authen();
at.setSessionID(id);

String sID = at.getSessionID();
```

Comment: if setSessionID  on A.class  to authen.java
I want to getSessionID on B.class from authen.java
How can i do this method ?

Comment: You can't, unless you make Authen a singleton, but then you can't have a different ID for A and B

Answer (score 0):

You should use at like below...

```
String id="1234";
Authen at = new Authen();
at.setSessionID(id);
String sID = at.getSessionID();
```

No need to renew at.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your sID is null is that you 'new' a brand new object as you declare 'at' object in the second time `Authen at = new Authen();`.
You do not need to initianite Authen again if you want to get the sID correctly.
Just do:

```
String id="1234";
Authen at = new Authen();
at.setSessionID(id);
String sID = at.getSessionID();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer the Authen instance from class A to B if it is needed there (assuming class A creates the instance of B):

```
class A {
    private void aMethod() {
        String id="1234";
        Authen at = new Authen();
        at.setSessionID(id);
        ...
        B b = new B(at);
    }
}

class B {
    private Authen authen;

    public B(Authen at) {
        this.authen = at;
        ...
    }

    private void anotherMethod() {
        String sID = this.authen.getSessionID();
        ...
    }
}
```

*obviously this code is not complete, just to show the main idea - and just one of many possibilities.*